# GWT EJB transferring objects

Tags: gwt, ejb, pojo

I have got a question because of the architecture of my project.

At the one side there is a GWT Package with the Client Side and also a Servlet to communicate with an EJB Project. On the other Side there is a EJB Project with Session Beans and Entities which should be stored in a database and send between GWT Client and the database. How can I realize that?

How can I send an Object from my Session Bean to the GWT Servlet, because the GWT Servlet doesn't know about the Entity Classes.

Answer (score 2):

Your `BeanServiceImpl` *can* know about your EJB entities. It's only the *client* side of the GWT project that can not. So, somewhere in your `server` package, you would have a translator/marshaller/converter to switch from your EJB entity `Company` to a `CompanyDTO` for the client-side. It can have all the same fields, really, just not the `@Entity` annotation, obviously. Like so:

```
private CompanyDTO convert(Company ejb) {
  CompanyDTO dto = new CompanyDTO(ejb.getName());
  dto.setAddress(ejb.getAddress());
  return dto;
}
```

Then your client-side GWT code, can deal with these DTOs, translating back to entities on the server-side when you need to perform a transaction.

Comment: Thank you, that works but it would produce duplicated Code and it would be more komplex. Have you ever tested the RequestFactory?

Comment: @ph09 Most definitely it duplicates code. RequestFactory could be an alternative, but I myself have not implemented any solution with it. I have looked into it, but in our architecture, it isn't completely cut-and-dry to implement.

Comment: I found a solution:
@OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST},
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<Person> personen = new Vector<Person>();

with the annotation FetchType.Eager your are able to send an Collection of Objects and their refernces to the Client Side.

Comment: @ph09 I'm glad you got it working! If you feel my answer was correct, you can accept it. If not, it would help the community if you summarized your complete solution in a new answer, and accepted it as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and I was able to send an Object from Client to an EJB an store it in a MYSQL Database:
http://www.vogella.de/articles/GWT/ar01s08.html

But when I try to send it back to the Client, I always get an Exception:
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type 'org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList' was not included in the set of types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class object could not be loaded. For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.: instance = {IndirectList: not instantiated}

Therefore I think you have to use DTO's..